# Multiple output formats for __str__

Tags: python, string

I want to write a `__str__` for my class. However, the class has many members and not all may always be relevant. I want the `__str__` to include only the key members by default, but include more if the user asks for more.

How can I do this? Can `__str__` take parameters (I am okay with giving them default values)? How will these parameters be passed when the user does `print(my_class_instance)`?

Comment: Just define separate methods that return strings and accept parameters

Comment: you probably want to implement [`__format__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179926/how-is-the-format-method-supposed-to-be-used-for-int) then.  it would  let you do `"{:essentials}".format(my_class_instance)` to render differently than `"{:raw}".format(my_class_instance)`

Comment: `def to_string(self, include_extras=None): (...)`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Sounds about right - why comment instead of answer?

Comment: @user8493571 was planning to then got distracted, thanks for the reminder, I have now!

Answer (score 0):

The most common way of doing this in python is to define [a `__format__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__) so that you can use format specifiers much like `"{:05.3f}"` can format floating point numbers.

If you only need 2 representations, one to be more user friendly and one to be more descriptive you may be able to get away with just defining `__str__` and `__repr__`, for context `__repr__` is used when displaying values in an interactive terminal or when calling `repr` or using `"{0!r}".format`.

Here is a sample code to get you started:

```
class Demo:
    def __init__(self, a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __repr__(self):
        # should usually have a repr method to show code representation
        return "Demo({0.a!r}, {0.b!r})".format(self)
    def __str__(self):
        # str should give user friendly representation, default format
        return "Demo()"
    def __format__(self, spec):
        # format for more specific details
        if spec == "": # usually empty spec should be equivalent to str.
            return str(self)
        elif spec == "d":
            return "(a:{0.a}, b:{0.b})".format(self)
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError("unsupported spec: {!r}".format(spec))

x = Demo("A", "B")
print("str: {0}, repr: {0!r}, spec='d': {0:d}".format(x))

print("WILL THROW ERROR: {0:OTHER_SPEC}".format(x))
```

You can make any format spec you wish, what ever is passed into the specifier will be passed to the `__format__` method as a string.